# UI5 sap.m.ColumnListItem busy property not working (possible bug?)

Tags: sapui5

I've found something which I believe could be a UI5 bug, but wanted to follow up with the community first.

I was trying to put a table row in busy state while I'm doing some processing. When I got the line (ColumnListItem) on an event, I tried the regular `.setBusy(true)`, nothing happened. Then I tried a table sample from SAP Samples and it didn't work either. I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> Diagnostics tool to set it when testing SAP's code, but obviously could do it differently.

I tried a UI control within the ColumnListItem and the parent (Table itself) which are working fine. And if I try a List with a StandardListItem, it works fine.

So if you open the [SAP Responsive Table](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Table/preview) and open the diagnostics tool, find any of the displayed ColumnListItems and flag busy, nothing will happen.

[image: My Test]

Any thoughts?

Comment: I just added an update to [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50512073/5846045). May I know **why** you'd like to set a single Item busy?

Comment: Thank you for the update, it's sad to see they don't plan to change that. I wanted to make inline editable inputs where they are dependent on previous column to populate something, but instead of locking the 1 field I thought it would look much better to lock the entire row..Same applies for inline editing+saving..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that ColumnListItems are rendered with the HTML tag `<tr>` which is one of the [forbidden tags](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/search?l=JavaScript&q=%22rforbiddentags%22) to contain busy indicator. UI5 then outputs the following warning:

> BusyIndicator cannot be placed in elements with tag 'TR'.

[image: UI5 TR busy indicator warning]

It's unclear whether it was intentional or not. I couldn't find any references in the documentation that ColumnListItems are not supposed to display BusyIndicators.

I just filed an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2041
I'll update this answer as soon as it's clarified.

---

**Update:** Unfortunately, the framework developers have decided not to support busy states for `sap.m.ColumnListItem` and they're [sticking to that decision](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2041#issuecomment-395358986).